Can Ubuntu 24 be installed on an empty partition using minimal.squashfs through the terminal?
I encountered an issue while attempting to install Ubuntu via live USB. The graphical installer did not offer the option to choose manual partitioning. Even when I selected the empty partition, the installer showed an empty partition list. I also faced a similar situation while selecting the hard drive to install the bootloader. As a result, I had to install Ubuntu 24 alongside another previously installed version of Ubuntu.
Can Ubuntu 24 be installed on an empty partition using minimal.squashfs through the terminal?

In this guide, we'll install a fully functional and bootable Ubuntu 24 on an empty partition using minimal.squashfs file via the terminal. You can use either the current Ubuntu/Linux or Ubuntu Live USB disk.
 However, before proceeding, please make sure to create a backup of your data. Also, if you're not familiar with commands like mkfs, mount, umount, and /dev/XXX, I advise you not to read this answer.
1- Formatting the partition

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/XXX    
#make sure to select the right litters to replace with xxx

2- Mount that empty partition
 sudo mkdir /ubuntu             #If don't work, use sudo -i at first
 sudo mount /dev/XXX /ubuntu    #make sure to select the right litters to replace with xxx

3- Extract the files to the empty partition
sudo unsquashfs -f -d /ubuntu /xxx/minimal.squashfs      
#make sure to select the right path of minimal.squashfs to replace with xxx.

If you haven't done so already, it's recommended that you install squashfs-tools.
if you are not using live Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, go to the step no.4
If you're using live Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, you'll need to mount another partition to copy the minimal.squashfs file to it. You can find the minimal.squashfs in the ISO file or the Ubuntu live USB in the /casper directory.
to mount another partition:
mkdir sdaz
mount /dev/sdaz  sdaz  #replace z with your partition` that inclode the minimal.squashfs file

copy the minimal.squashfs file to this partition, and put the path in the previous step.


Please make sure that you have entered the correct path in the previous step before proceeding further.
To complete the installation process without any errors:
4- Configure external mount points:
sudo mount --bind /dev /ubuntu/dev
sudo mount --bind /run /ubuntu/run

5- Access chroot environment
sudo chroot /ubuntu

6- Define chroot environment
mount none -t proc /proc
mount none -t sysfs /sys
mount none -t devpts /dev/pts
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C

7- Configure machine-id and divert
dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id
ln -fs /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl 
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl                    

8- Upgrade packages
apt-get -y upgrade

9- Install packages needed for the System (Install Grub and Linux Kernel)
apt-get install -y grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends linux-generic

In this step, you will see recommended grub and kernel packages for your device. If they are not listed in my commands, please install them.

In case, you are unable to access the internet, you can locate all these packages in the Ubuntu ISO file, or buntu Live USB disk under the /pool directory. You can then copy all these packages to the /ubuntu directory and execute the following command: dpkg -i *.deb, or make new folder /deb as an example, and execute the following command: dpkg -i /ubuntu/deb/*.deb

It's possible to install drivers and custom apps using the terminal either online or by placing them in the /deb directory and executing the command dpkg -i /deb/*.deb.
10- Grub (update the boot menu in the new OS)
update-grub

11- Create fstab
 A simple example of fstab is
echo "/dev/sdxx / ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> /etc/fstab      
## Inside chroot! 
#make sure to sellect the right litters to replace with xx

12- Cleanup the chroot environment
truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id
rm /sbin/initctl
dpkg-divert --rename --remove /sbin/initctl
apt-get clean
rm -rf /tmp/* ~/.bash_history
umount /proc
umount /sys
umount /dev/pts
export HISTSIZE=0

exit

13- Unbind mount points
sudo umount /ubuntu/dev
sudo umount /ubuntu/run

14- update the boot menu in the current OS
 This step when you use Ubuntu/Linux from your device
sudo update-grub

 If you use Ubuntu Live from a USB drive, cancel this command, install the grub bootloader on the Hard disk, or use the boot-repair package.
 
15- Reboot
 After rebooting your computer, you can set up your account, local, and language settings. Everything should work properly on the first try after the splash screen ends.
Update:
You can format the partition as the root of the file system / and copy all files from the squashfs file in one command using the -d option in the mkfs.ext4 command like this example:
sudo mkfs.ext4 -d /media/username/disk /dev/sda7

In this command, partition 7 in hard disk a will be the root of the file system /, and the system files will be copied from the squashfs file mounted at /media/username/disk.
This command helped me to avoid the lock sign on all directories in the root. this lock sign appeared after using the unsquashfs command.
These pages helped me in these steps:
How to create a bootable fully functional Ubuntu from debootstrap ?
Installation/FromLinux
How to create a custom Ubuntu live from scratch
Create USB drive contains multi Ubuntu versions
mkfs.exte4 Ubuntu  manuals
