Ubuntu 24 installation stuck at keyboard layout screen
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS alongside with Windows 11 on my Asus Vivobook 15 Pro. I have burnt the ISO file to a USB pendrive, and can boot from it to try Ubuntu. When I try to install Ubuntu following the guided procedure, I can go through the Language and Accessibility screens without issues. When I get at the Keyboard layout screen, the installation get stuck when I click on the Next button, it turns into the loading wheel icon (see image below) which gets stuck, i.e. no spinning, after (at most) few seconds.

Procedure and attempts
This is what I have done so far:

Download the ISO file from Ubuntu Downloads and verify the checksum. I have tried both with Ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10 with same result.
Create the bootable USB. I have tested several options:

Rufus (both ISO and DD modes) from Windows 11 system
BalenaEtcher from Windows 11 system
StartupDiskCreator from Ubuntu 20 system


Boot from the USB and select the 'Try or install Ubuntu' (tried booting with and without the nomodeset option)
Go through the guided installation procedure, up to the Keyboard layout screen where I get stuck as described above.

Additional info
When trying the Ubuntu Live ISO, everything works well, apart from my laptop keyboard not being recognized. It might be unrelated, but it looks suspicious to me.
Connecting an external USB keyboard (correctly recognized) did not change the outcome.
For the sake of completeness, the keyboard has problems with the 6.8 kernel version that comes with Ubuntu 24.04, but it works fine with kernel version 6.10 (I have tried it with an Ubuntu 20.04 installation).
Questions

How can I install Ubuntu 24.04 without following the guided procedure?
Is it possible to inspect the Ubuntu installation process to inspect the command(s) that causes the issue?

Thank you very much!

you can complete the installation in English and after booting with Ubuntu add the Italian layout

you can install Ubuntu using the terminal as this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513407/can-ubuntu-24-be-installed-on-an-empty-partition-using-minimal-squashfs-through

@Talaat thanks for the advices. I have already tried going through the procedure with the English keyboard layout, and the result is just the same. Sorry for not including the info. I have solved installing Ubuntu 23.10 and upgrading to 24.04. Thanks anyway for your valuable advice!

I had problems with the installers, the keyboard, and NVIDIA drivers (external monitors). The solution was to install kubuntu 24.10

i had the same issue and solved it. I checked the link.desktop of the installer and ran it in the terminal. After that i saw error msgs about the network adapters. I could install by doing:

disable all network adapters at the BIOS (ethernet and wifi)
launch the installer without internet
after the installer ends, reboot, re-enable the network adapters and...
Finally enjoy Ubuntu :)


For me, on my Lenovo X13 G4 (Intel 13th Gen i5-1335U) disabling all network options in the BIOS did not help.
Instead from the installers GUI I clicked the top left icon to open the search page. Then naviagted to network settings from there. Disabled Wi-Fi, Network and Mobile Network there by changing the switch of each setting to "off". After that it let me pass through the installation just fine.

Improve formatting
